# favicon when opening image in new tab

Tags: favicon

When I right click on my website logo and click on open image in new tab, there is only a generic favicon.

Is there a way to pass the favicon information to this specific page?

[not the websites favicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMFN2.png)

Comment: What are yo want to do?

Comment: I want to have my websites favicon on the "open image in new tab"-page, but there is only this other favicon. How can I change that?

Comment: You need to put a favicon.ico in the root directory of your website (as I mentioned in my answer below) **and also** be hosting the image on your *own site, not imgur* as it appears that image is currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you have a favicon.ico file in the root directory of your website browsers *should* (as in: are supposed to) use this for any file served from that domain.

Comment: ah okay, so I have it in root/img and I reference it - but it should be directly in root? do I even need to reference it then?

Comment: Hi @guti2k if you have a `favicon.ico` file it in the web root it will [automatically work without linking in all browsers (ref: Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use), although I still recommend adding multiple sized PNG's to your `<head>` for highest quality in those operating systems that support it. ([Favicon Cheat Sheet (ref: GitHub)](https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet). Those PNG images can reside in whatever directory you like. Thanks for marking as accepted! :)